# PHP and Javascript and SQL create form input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have spent quite a lot of time trying to figure out how to get an autocomplete input box using values from an SQLi database. I can get the values to show up but I do not have a clue how to make it into a html form which can process the input.

I need to find a way of getting the value to be assigned to the ID. I am not quite sure how else to put it.

Here is my script,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "timedRun";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $sql = "select firstName, lastName from students";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $selected_name="";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "\"".$row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName']."\" ,";
            };
        };
      ?>
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "test";
?>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think the problem is in connection details you have define in above code, it should be in separate file and define in top of the file i.e. `include('connection.php');`. Above code is working fine here in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you don't actually create a form, you just echo the output.
Here is a simple first step to presenting a form with the values you want.
**Be careful** with the form encapsulation and all the php opening and closing tags, as well as where you start and end your form. It all plays a big role on whether it would work as desired.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "timedRun";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $sql = "select firstName, lastName from students";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $selected_name="";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
            ?>
            <form>
            <?php
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="<?php echo $row['firstName']; ?>"><br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="<?php echo $row['lastName']; ?>"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <?php
            };
            ?>
            </form>
            <?php
        };
      ?>
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
```

If you don't want to get the first and last name as placeholders but as the value of the input boxes, then you should replace the "placeholder" atrribute of the input with "value".

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried it but it seems to be that the autocomplete function now no longer works. This is the extra which I have added to this script. <body>
<input id="tags">
</body>
</html>

Comment: what is that 
`$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags });`
 for?

Comment: I am not quite sure as this came from another source but it seems to be the command to create the autocompletion box itself.

Comment: if you are in desperate need of presenting the data with jquery, then this link might help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget--net-10560

Otherwise, you could remove the javascript in whole and just produce the form with pure PHP and HTML